# Visual Studio registry capture utility has encountered a problem

Tags: visual-studio-2008, j#

I recently reinstalled my development machine and went from 32 bit Windows Vista to 64 bit Windows 7. I'm running VS2008.

Some of my .NET applications still use J#, which now causes problems. The program still runs, but when I want to deploy it (I'm using a setup project to create a .msi), I get this error:

"Visual Studio registry capture utility has encountered a problem"

How can I fix this?
This error does not occur with other programs (those written purely in C#).

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Yes, this is a known bug with Win7 and VS2008, in creating an installer that exposes COM objects.

[Here is the workaround](https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/ViewFeedback.aspx?FeedbackID=466157)

Thanks @RogerFraser for the tip as I was having the same problem

To solve.

1. Locate regcap.exe here: **C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment**
2. Right click and select properties.
3. Select Compatibility tab
4. Check box to Run this program in compatibility mode.
5. Select Windows Vista SP2 in the OS drop-down.
6. Click Ok and Recompile.

HTH.

Comment: I guess you should not believe everything you read on the Internet. This did not fox the problem for me.

Comment: What if you don't have that folder - C:\Program Files\Microsoft Visual Studio 9.0\Common7\Tools\Deployment?

Answer (score 3):

This did not work for me until I came across [this blog post](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/smondal/archive/2010/05/19/regcap-exe-crashes-while-building-a-setup-project-in-visual-studio-2008.aspx) where the poster looked at the debug information and found a buffer overflow error with long paths. I put the solution into C:\temp and I was able to compile it after following the steps posted by Noam and Kris. This was on a project upgraded from VS2005 to VS2010 on Windows 7 x64.

Comment: And I found this useful for VS2005 on Win7 x64: https://connect.microsoft.com/VisualStudio/feedback/details/466157/registry-capture-utility-win-7-rc1?wa=wsignin1.0

Answer (score 0):

Unfortunately it didn't work for me, still getting the same error. Using 
Windows 7 Enterprise Edition, 64 Bit.

That's the error details (German only, sorry):

```
Problemereignisname:    BEX
  Anwendungsname:   REGCAP.EXE
  Anwendungsversion:    9.0.21022.8
  Anwendungszeitstempel:    47316c84
  Fehlermodulname:  MSVCR90.dll
  Fehlermodulversion:   9.0.30729.4926
  Fehlermodulzeitstempel:   4a1743c1
  Ausnahmeoffset:   0003689c
  Ausnahmecode: c0000417
  Ausnahmedaten:    00000000
  Betriebsystemversion: 6.1.7600.2.0.0.256.4
  Gebietsschema-ID: 3079
  Zusatzinformation 1:  0a73
  Zusatzinformation 2:  0a7372810d093ef4e8ab14e85634e08a
  Zusatzinformation 3:  6150
  Zusatzinformation 4:  6150f9546d0a47d70659c34cf83b2016
```