# C# WinForms installation project error - Microsoft (R) Visual Studio registry capture utility has stopped working

Tags: visual-studio-2017

I have a setup project for a WinForms app on Visual Studio 2017 running on Windows 10. After one of the updates I made to Visual Studio version 15.4.X this error message started to appear 3 times every time I build the setup project:

[image]

I found similar questions about this same error here:

- [Visual Studio registry capture utility has stopped working, error compiling C# project in Windows7](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2334005/visual-studio-registry-capture-utility-has-stopped-working-error-compiling-c-sh)
- [Visual Studio registry capture utility has encountered a problem](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1708541/visual-studio-registry-capture-utility-has-encountered-a-problem)

but these are for previous versions of Visual Studio and for Windows 7 so I couldn't follow their solution because the path they describe doesn't exist.
I got up to

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools

but that's it, I don't have a "Deployment" folder and no regcap.exe file

Comment: There is also one here: C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\bin but otherwise, just go in task manager, right click and "open file location". If you don't see it, you can also use SysInternal's procmon (Process Monitor), before building, to find out where it's launched from (and possibly by whom)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 14.0\Common7\Tools

That is a VS2015 directory, you have version 15 aka VS2017.  Be sure to locate the VS2017 install directory first, it was significantly changed from prior VS versions.  Start from

> C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\

There is a subdirectory there that matches the edition name, like Enterprise, Professional, Community.  Navigate into that directory, you now see the Common7 subdirectory.

The regcap.exe utility was moved as well, it now lives inside

> Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\bin\regcap.exe

Answer (score 1):

I found the same issue for VS 2017 on Windows 10 version 1709 only. A previous version 1703 works well. Fore more details please see the link below:

https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/486fae72-d825-4a79-a17f-6f66e15c6bc8/visual-studio-2017-installer-project-issue-on-windows-10-1709?forum=visualstudiogeneral#d418a5da-5a36-4b3d-b196-e8beb97dfded

Comment: I had the same problem on Windows 10, VS 2017 build 15.6.4. I set the compatibility for `C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio\2017\Professional\Common7\IDE\CommonExtensions\Microsoft\VSI\bin\regcap.exe` to Windows 7 and everything works fine

Comment: If you look carefully at build output window you will find warnings about unable to get a registration info. The error message popup is not shown after setting the compatibility but the msi is created without having proper info about OCX registration. So that, the setup doesn't register OCX files during installation.

Answer (score 0):

- To fix the regap.exe-issue you should update VSI-Installer Projects extensions to the newest version (currently version 0.8.8).
- You can get it from Tools->Extension and Updates->Tools. Select "Updates", "Visual Studio Marketplace" within Visual Studio. Look for "Microsoft Visual Studio 2017 Installer Projects" and apply the update.
- In my case the installer project could not capture ComInterop-tlb registry info during build.
- Applying the update fixed all issues.
  -- The fix is confirmed here: https://social.msdn.microsoft.com/Forums/vstudio/en-US/486fae72-d825-4a79-a17f-6f66e15c6bc8/visual-studio-2017-installer-project-issue-on-windows-10-1709?forum=visualstudiogeneral&prof=required